# where to put facebook ajax sign in file

Tags: facebook, yii, facebook-login, yii-extensions

i'm currently trying to migrate my site to yii. (still new to it too) in my site i have a facebook login code that looks like this

```
function updateButton(response) {
                var b = document.getElementById("{$this->fbLoginButtonId}");
                b.onclick = function(){
                    $("#{$this->fbLoginButtonId}").button("loading");
                    FB.login(function(response) {
                        if(response.authResponse) {
                            $('#processing').modal({show: true, backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});
                            FB.api('/me', function(user) {
                                $.ajax({ type : 'post'
                                    , url: '{$this->facebookLoginUrl}'
                                    , data: ({ user: user })
                                    , dataType: 'json'
                                    , success: function(data){
                                        if(data.error == 0){
                                            window.location.href = data.success;
                                        } else {
                                            $('#processing').modal('hide');
                                            showError(data.error);
                                            $("#{$this->fbLoginButtonId}").button("reset");
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            });    
                        } else { $("#{$this->fbLoginButtonId}").button("reset"); }
                    }, {scope: '{$this->facebookPermissions}'});
                }
        }
```

the line **url: '{$this->facebookLoginUrl}'** basically points to the file that does the authentication. in Yii, i put that file in **protected/controllers/facebookcontroller.php**

```
class FacebookController extends Controller {

    public $defaultAction = 'facebook';

    public function actionFacebook() {
        if (app()->request->isAjaxRequest) {
            $user = app()->request->getParam('user');
            Shared::debug($user);
            // verify one last time that facebook knows this guy
            if($user['id'] === app()->facebook->getUser()){
                $model = User::model()->findByEmail($user['email']);
                if(!empty($model)){
                    // facebook email matches one in the user database
                    $identity = new UserIdentity( $model->email , null );
                    $identity->_ssoAuth = true;
                    $identity->authenticate();
                    if($identity->errorCode === UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE){
                        app()->user->login($identity, null);
                        echo json_encode(array('error' => false, 'success' => url('/')));
                        app()->end();
                    } else {
                        echo json_encode(array('error' => 'System Authentication Failed', 'code' => 'auth'));
                        app()->end();
                    }
                } else {
                    // nothing found, this person should register
                    // write query to input into database!!!
                }
            } else {
                // fb user id past from ajax does not match who facebook says they are...
                echo json_encode(array('error' => 'Facebook Authentication Failed', 'code' => 'fb_auth'));
                app()->end();
            }
        } else {
            throw new CHttpException(403);
        }
    }

}
```

basically what do i put here **url: '{$this->facebookLoginUrl}'** ?? i tried `http://localhost/facebook.html` but doesn't work. i get this error on **firebug**

```
<h1>PHP Error [8]</h1>
<p>Undefined index: email (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/protected/controllers/FacebookController.php:13)</p>
<pre>#0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/protected/controllers/FacebookController.php(13): CWebApplication->handleError()
#1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/yii/web/actions/CInlineAction.php(49): FacebookController->actionFacebook()
#2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/yii/web/CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams()
#3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/yii/web/CController.php(286): FacebookController->runAction()
#4 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/yii/web/CController.php(265): FacebookController->runActionWithFilters()
#5 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/yii/web/CWebApplication.php(282): FacebookController->run()
#6 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/yii/web/CWebApplication.php(141): CWebApplication->runController()
#7 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/yii/base/CApplication.php(180): CWebApplication->processRequest()
#8 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/index.php(25): CWebApplication->run()
</pre>
```

the **ajax post response** looks like this..

```
user[birthday]  MM/DD/YYYY
user[first_name]    name
user[gender]    male
user[hometown][id]  106031246101856
user[hometown][name]    CITY, STATE
user[id]    598482999
user[last_name] LASTNAME
user[link]  https://www.facebook.com/ID
user[locale]    en_US
user[location][id]  106031246101856
user[location][name]    CITY, STATE
user[middle_name]   MIDDLENAME
user[name]  FULLNAME
user[timezone]  -8
user[updated_time]  2013-12-15T16:43:03+0000
user[username]  USERNAME
user[verified]  true
```

Answer (score 0):

Yii generates url as http://www.example.com/index.php?r={controller_id}/{action_id}.

So in your case url will be http://www.example.com/index.php?r=facebook/facebook.

Learn how yii manges url's [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url).

Comment: i set `'urlSuffix'=>'.html'`, and my file is in `localhost/facebook.php` i don't get a 404 error. the POST respond is above, how do i write it to db?

Comment: You are trying to edit your existing code according to yii, The right way is create the same logic in yii with fresh code. If you are going to same approach then why Yii?

Comment: like i said i'm still new to yii. but for testing purposes i put it in main directory. if i put it in my `controller/facebook.php` still the question remains, how do i write it to db? how would my facebook.php call `actionFacebook()` in my `protected/controllers/facebookcontroller.php` (code above) ?

Comment: Also go through all the steps http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/, It will be enough to leran all the basic concepts of Yii.